# Convert numbers from a file to binary notation

Tags: c, binary

I have a program to convert numbers from 0 to 255 into binary notation using spaces and asterisks. I want to use it to convert numbers from a `.txt` file into their binary notation, something like this:

```
./binary < binaryData.txt
 60:   ****
 66:  *    *
128: *
...
```

How can I accomplish this?

This is the code I've got so far, but it doesn't any input:

```
int main(void) {
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;

    int v = 0;
    //printf("%d: ", v);

    for (a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
        for (b = 0; b < 2; b++) {
            for (c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
                for (d = 0; d < 2; d++) {
                    for (e = 0; e < 2; e++) {
                        for (f = 0; f < 2; f++) {
                            for (g = 0; g < 2; g++) {
                                for (h = 0; h < 2; h++) {
                                    printf("%3d: ", v);

                                    if (a) printf("*");
                                    else printf(" ");

                                    if (b) printf("*");
                                    else printf(" ");

                                    if (c) printf("*");
                                    else printf(" ");

                                    if (d) printf("*");
                                    else printf(" ");

                                    if (e) printf("*");
                                    else printf(" ");

                                    if (f) printf("*");
                                    else printf(" ");

                                    if (g) printf("*");
                                    else printf(" ");

                                    if (h) printf("*");
                                    else printf(" ");

                                    printf("\n");
                                    v++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is too complex with that many nested `for` loops!

Comment: What's your input? What is the file format?

Comment: I edited your post to make it more comprehensible. Feel free to change it if I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `scanf()` to get the numbers as input, and then print their binary representation. Keep scanning until `scanf()` returns `EOF`, which means that you have reached the end of the input.

Here's what you're looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;

    while (scanf("%d", &i) != EOF) {
        printf("%3d: ", i);
        printf(i & 128 ? "*" : " ");
        printf(i &  64 ? "*" : " ");
        printf(i &  32 ? "*" : " ");
        printf(i &  16 ? "*" : " ");
        printf(i &   8 ? "*" : " ");
        printf(i &   4 ? "*" : " ");
        printf(i &   2 ? "*" : " ");
        printf(i &   1 ? "*" : " ");
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After compiling, call the program from a shell like this:

```
./program < data.txt
```

---

Example input file `data.txt`:

```
234
2
221
24
89
22
```

Output:

```
234: *** * * 
  2:       * 
221: ** *** *
 24:    **   
 89:  * **  *
 22:    * **
```

Comment: I don't believe `0b10000000` et al. is a standard numerical format in C.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons yeah that's a built-in GCC/Clang extension.

Comment: Not exactly what I need... Like there are many numbers data from data.txt to generating number into binary with stars...

Comment: 60:   ****  
 66:  *    * 
128: *       
128: *       
128: *       
 66:  *    * 
 60:   ****  
  0:         
124:  *****  
130: *     * 
128: *       
124:  *****  
  2:       * 
130: *     * 
124:  *****  
  0:         
254: ******* 
128: *       
128: *       
252: ******  
  2:       * 
  2:       * 
252: ******  
  0:         
124:  *****  
134: *    ** 
138: *   * * 
146: *  *  * 
162: * *   * 
194: **    * 
124:  *****  
  0:         
124:  *****  
134: *    ** 
138: *   * * 
146: *  *  * 
162: * *   * 
194: **    * 
124:  *****

Comment: @MikeODell wait... is the data.txt a long list of numbers?

Comment: From data.txt I created.

Comment: Yes, sir.. That's what I meant. Sorry for the confusion @Marco Bonelli

Comment: Made another answer so you can see it.

Comment: @MikeODell ok, edited again. Try it out now., and be careful when copying.

Comment: Sorry for another answers but I'm new to Stackoverflow but THANK YOU THANk you!

Comment: @MikeODell You're welcome. If my answer solved your problem don't forget to click the check mark under the vote buttons to accept it, you can also upvote it if you want.